# Social Business Toolkit: Sametime chat only with local installed Sametime Client possible?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus, ibm-sbt, sametime

I'm using SBT SDK on a XPage.
After mastering a few traps at the beginning it works fine.
Livenames are properly displayed.

But now a got another problem.
If you click on a available person, a context menu is displayed, where you can choose 'CHAT' or 'VCARD'.

If I click on CHAT a URL like this ist called:

```
http://localhost:59449/stwebapi/loggedin?jsonp=stproxy.connect.callback.setAvailable&wait=true&time=1407834968761&fqdn=sametime.lotus.com
```

I found out that you have to install Sametime Connect Client locally at every computer, because it is providing a small webserver at port 59449.
That's impossible because I want to use Sametime on a public website.

I'm pretty sure that there is another way.
Somebody an idea?

thanks 
Marcus

Answer (score 1):

@user2776693 - There are two ways: 
1 - using the Sametime Local Web API 
   The local web api uses a configurable port (the default is mentioned above), to communicate back and forth from a web site which embeds or calls the configurable port using jsonp, meaning the javascript of the site wraps the sametime calls.

2 - using the Sametime Web Chat/Web Proxy
It means that the Sametime Web Chat is embedded as JavaScript on the page, and loaded using the appropriate JS libraries, and can have some pretty advanced features.  There is a demo site off of greenhouse.lotus.com, and you can sign up for an account on that site.

you can download the sdk, and find many examples of using the local web api and web chat. 
http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/download/nochargesearch.jsp?q0=&k=ALL&S_TACT=104CBW71&status=Active&b=Lotus&sr=1&q=sametime+sdk&ibm-search=Search

Download Version 9.0 IFR1 
Extract with Zip 
Go to Examples and samples

Comment: Looks fine, I'll try your second hint. Thank you